# In a room of 5 people, 2 people talk to each other ...

Tags: combinatorics

In a room of $5$ people, $2$ people meet and talk. How many ways can this happen?

I believe that the answer is $5\choose2$ = $10$. Is this correct? or would I need to do permutation?

Comment: It is correct.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shaking hands problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208090/shaking-hands-problem)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is correct. Since it takes two people to have a conversation, you count all subsets of size 2.